# Decipher Client-Side Rules binary definition for Microsoft Outlook

Tags: outlook

Outlook saves its client-side rule definitions in a binary blob in a hidden message in the Inbox folder of the default store for a profile. The hidden message is named *"Outlook Rules Organizer"* with a message class `IPM.RuleOrganizer`. The binary blob is saved in property 0x6802. The same binary blob is written to the exported RWZ file when you manually export the rules through the Rules and Alerts Wizard.

Has anyone deciphered the layout of this binary blob?

Comment: I started a CodePlex project to organize Outlook rules (primarily sorting) a couple of years ago and recently revisited it.  Depending on what you need, you can possibly find some useful info there. [link](https://rwzreader.codeplex.com).  I haven't gotten to the point of parsing the individual criteria and actions because I didn't need it, but I may continue it as an exercise.

Comment: It is 2019 and it still looks lik RWZ files are not easy to access. I just stumbled upon http://www.outlookrulesmanager.com/ but I cannot judge how trustworthy this service is. There are also many [MS Technet Blog entries](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/a78d158a-9278-45ee-aeff-a7f18fee41f6/is-it-possible-to-edit-or-print-rwz-files-outlook-rules-export-file?forum=exchangesvrclientslegacy) which conclude that there still is no solution like `rwz2xml`.

Answer (score 6):

I had exactly the same problem, so I spent a (too) long time looking into the format.

I developed a library https://github.com/hughbe/OutlookRulesReader that contains a specification and reference implementation library (in Swift) for reading and writing Outlook Rules Files

A full description of the format can be found [here](https://github.com/hughbe/OutlookRulesReader/raw/master/docs/RWZ%20Format.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, that is a tough one...

Here's the [server side rules protocol](http://209.85.173.104/search?q=cache:TUrkQGhrNpgJ:download.microsoft.com/download/5/D/D/5DD33FDF-91F5-496D-9884-0A0B0EE698BB/%255BMS-OXORULE%255D.pdf+%22IPM.RuleOrganizer%22&hl=en&ct=clnk&cd=7&gl=us)

According to this [cryptic affair](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579224(EXCHG.80).aspx) it looks as though you'll probably need to spend some time in Reflector as well...

Ah, these look closer to the mark and promising, give them a look:

[Description of programming with Outlook rules](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324568)

[How to use the Rule.dll sample to create an inbox rule in Visual Basic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251125/)

In general, Microsoft is explicitly saying it hasn't kept the documentation up on the rules in the last two versions and so the caveats...